# How to hide specific button after Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Got a multiple buttons with thesame class, though with different id how can I hide a specific button based  on the clicked button!

My Code

**Btn*"

```
<button class="join" id="join_2">Join Group</button>
```

**jQuery/Ajax**

```
$(".join").off().click(function (){
  Var group_id = this.id;

  $.ajax({
    //
    //
    //
    Success: function(data){
      $(group_id).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

But this doesn't hide the button clicked after success... Probably the **Var** isn't a superGlobal..
Does anyone has idea how I can solve this..

Comment: It should work, assuming the AJAX actually returns successfully - have you debugged that? (Although just beware of case-sensitivity - rewrite `Var` to `var` and `Success` to `success` and try again, too.

Comment: Ah hang on I forgot about the # being needed in the selector (see below). But you can just write `$(this)` anyway to get the clicked element into a jQuery object anyway - no need to mess about with the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
$('#' + group_id).hide();
```

As you just got the id and not the element itself. Therefore you still need to add `#` while hiding that element

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the # at the start of the selector.

But anyway you don't really need to mess about with the ID at all - you can do it as follows instead:

```
$(".join").off().click(function (){
  var btn = $(this); //create jQuery object direct from the element

  $.ajax({
    //
    //
    //
    success: function(data){
      btn.hide();
    }
  });
});
```